# make a beep sound in firefox toolbar ?

Tags: javascript, firefox, toolbar

I'm making a firefox toolbar and it contains a timer that counts down, I want to alert the user when there are only 10 seconds left with a beep sound, how can I make that ?

I tried the code below but it didn't work, knowing that it works fine in normal pages.

```
var snd = new Audio("snd.wav");
snd.play();
```

Comment: accessibility.typeaheadfind.soundURL ??

Comment: the soundURL is fine, when I call it, it pops up an IDM dialog box to download the sound file, and it also works fine with the normal pages.